# Windows XP fails to connect to Netgear wireless router

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-router

I'm having an issue connecting. I just moved in with my daughter who has a Netgear router connected to her laptop and she is using Windows 7. My HP Pavilion zv6000 laptop is using Windows XP and just two weeks prior to moving I was able to connect to my brother-in-law's newly purchased router (not Netgear).

I have the correct network key and can find the correct router, but when I select connect it acts like it's going to connect, then it just reverts to 'choose a wireless network'. The only way that I've successfully connected to the router is via Ethernet cable.

I called Netgear and HP, but they won't help because my laptop and the router are both out of warranty.

**Why does the connection attempt fail?**

Comment: [Have you tried unplugging it, and plugging it back in?](http://i.imgur.com/p49Cu.png)

Comment: You should edit to provide more detail in your question. What encryption method does the Netgear router use? How about your laptop? Her laptop? Your old router? You may have a mismatch in your laptop [configuration](http://www.it.northwestern.edu/oncampus/wireless/wireless-connections/wireless-win.html).

Answer (score 1):

What encryption did the router that worked use?  Does the "new" router use the same type of encryption?  Some XP systems will require an update to support WPA2.  Check to see if your system has this and if that is what is needed for the new router.

[XP WPA Support Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1974)